# Using two Xcode projects with one target

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I have one app I am trying to build called "App". I have an Xcode project called `App.xcodeproj` that lives in a Xcode workspace called `App.xcworkspace`. That is all working.

*This is what I want:*

A second Xcode project (`AppCore.xcodeproj`) that I can separately build on iOS or Mac. However there is no need to actually run the project (app). It will be the data layer of my app.

I then need to be able to access the files inside `AppCore.xcodeproj` from `App.xcodeproj`.

---

**Update:**

In this project, I will be using CloudKit. The `Core` project is the only thing interacting with CloudKit, however the actually target (app) using CloudKit is the "main" project.

---

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial GIF:

[image]

**Remarks:**

You can add existing project as well, just drag it into you xCode project.

Comment: Now I have added, **Proj B** into my **Proj A**. Now, I have to call **Proj B** when I click a button which is inside **Proj A**. Is It Possible? Can u guide me?

Comment: Can u guide me?